# jboss clustering Query issue

Tags: jboss, jboss-cache

I have a small query regarding jboss clustering. If i have two nodes in cluster environment , If one node is down due to some reason , Will another node take the request?  Since both are in cluster mode , I assume thaet if one node is down , another should take the request.Is that correct? Anybody who have knowledge on jboss , please throw some light on this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The scenario your talking about is the Failover. Yes you are right, if you create a cluster(Group) and add two servers(Nodes) to the cluster then all the requests will go to either first node or the second. And if one of the JBoss node fails or stops then all the requests will be routed to the other node.

But to successfully create a JBoss cluster you will need to use a load balancer such as Apache, so that the load balancer will route the requests to the nodes in that cluster

Below are some docs that could help you understand in detail

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossmessaging/docs/usermanual-2.0.0.beta3/html/ha.html

http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r4/html/cluster.chapt.html